# load balance timeout SQL connection string

Tags: c#, sql

It seems that if there is a sql memory leak somewhere and you dont have time to find it you can use the load balance timeout option in a sql connection string to destory the connection after x seconds.

Am i right in assuming I can set the load balance time out to 30-40 seconds and then hunt for the leak latter, while in the mean time the leak will not affect my application too much.

Comment: What makes you suspect there is a "sql memory leak"?

Comment: Sql Connection leak sorry. My connection pool is running out of connections. I should've stated it as a sql connection leak not memory

Answer (score 1):

No. The **Load Balance Timeout** is the minimum time for the connection to live in the pool, it will not limit the life time of connections.

You might be looking for the **Connection Lifetime** setting, which will force connections to be closed when they are too old when returned to the pool, but that won't help you either, as the problem is that the connections aren't returned to the pool in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

(Would have added as a comment to Guffa but my rep isn't high enough)

You're nearly right about the behaviour of Load Balance Timeout, at least for .NET 3.5+, and likely earlier. When retrieving a connection from the pool, it kills any that have been open for the specified number of seconds. The normal use is of course for load balancing. Here's the ambiguous doco for .NET 3.5, with clarifying comments at the bottom:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

And here's a MS guy from 2004 saying the same thing:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/angelsb/archive/2004/09/20/231963.aspx

EDIT: I've just realised that this setting would not help the described case, because the connections are only destroyed when they're retrieved from the pool. Leaked connections are never retrieved from the pool again, since "leaking" means they never get returned to the pool.